# How can i store all my vector elements in a hash table c++

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, hashtable

### Code which i Have Done##

```
class vehicle
{
    public:
        vehicle();
        virtual ~vehicle();
        void addVehicle();
        void deleteVehicle();
        void printvehicle(vehicle v);
        void show();
        void showleft();
        void vehcileLoad();

    protected:

    private:
    std::string pltno;
    date dt;
    lime arrive;
    lime departure;
};


int static totalvehicle=0,totalcar=0,totalamt=0,i=0,z=0;
void vehicle::addVehicle()
{

      vehicle *v = new vehicle;
      std::cin.ignore();
      std::cout<<"Enter vehicle number : ";
      std::getline(std::cin, v->pltno);
      std::cout<<"Enter arrival time in hours minutes and seconds : ";
      std::cin>>v->arrive.hh>>v->arrive.col1>>v->arrive.mm>>v->arrive.col2>>v->arrive.ss;
      std::cout<<"Enter date in day month and year: ";
      std::cin>>v->dt.day>>v->dt.sym1>>v->dt.month>>v->dt.sym2>>v->dt.year;




      veh.at(i).pltno=v->pltno;
      veh.at(i).arrive.hh=v->arrive.hh;
      veh.at(i).arrive.mm=v->arrive.mm;
      veh.at(i).arrive.ss=v->arrive.ss;
      veh.at(i).dt.day=v->dt.day;
      veh.at(i).dt.month=v->dt.month;
      veh.at(i).dt.year=v->dt.year;
```

### What i hope to accomplish

This is part of the code i have this is also how i store data into the vector using `v->pltno = ...`  etc I would like to know how can i store all elements within the vector into a hash table please help i am clueless how can i store all items with veh and vehleft into a hash table 1 being for vehciles in parking and 1's which have left

what would the code look like to perform such a task?

### Other code of vector

```
std::vector<vehicle> veh(100);
std::vector<vehicle> vehleft(100);
```

Thank you?

Comment: `vehicle *v = new vehicle;` -- Why are you using `new` to create your vehicles?  Simply `vehicle v;` is all that you need to do.  There is no need to introduce dynamic allocation or pointers.

Comment: *I would like to know how can i store all elements within the vector into a hash table* -- `std::unordered_map<int, Vehicle>` -- Do you know how to use this?  A `std::unordered_map` is a hash table.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't `ignore` ahead of a `getline` just in case there is a newline in the stream. Sooner or later you will find a case where there is no newline and you discard data you needed. Instead place the `ignore` after operations that leave unwanted newlines in the stream.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No i honestly don't know this well thats why i am asking for help?

Comment: [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).  It is literally one line of code to create the map of those vehicles (the `int` is the number, and the `Vehicle` in the map is the vehicle object).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So the line that you mentioned above but instead of vehicle i put veh?

Comment: Actually, a `std::unordered_map<std::string, Vehicle>`, where the string is the plate number is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your vehicle objects are stored in a `std::vector<Vehicle>`, using a [std::unordered_map<std::string, Vehicle>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) is a very simple way of getting a hash table populated with the vehicles:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
//... 
class Vehicle
{
//...
};

void foo()
{
   std::vector<Vehicle> veh(100);
   //...
   std::unorderd_map<std::string, Vehicle> mapVehicle;
   for (auto& v : veh)
   { 
      // add the vehicle v to the hash table
      mapVehicle[v.pltNo] = v;
   }
   //...
}
```

Once you do that, you lookup a vehicle using the plate number:

```
Vehicle& v = mapVehicle["ABC123"]; // this is the vehicle with license plate ABC123
```

or to be safe (since using [] to do a search will add an empty entry if not found), you can check if the vehicle exists using `std::unordered_map::find()`:

```
auto iter = mapVehicle.find("ABC123");
if (iter != mapVehicle.end())
{
   Vehicle& v = iter->second;
}
```

Comment: Hey paul thanks for the function and code however i am getting issues running it in the implemntaiton file it says ` Unordered map is not a member of std` and `Map Vehcile was not delcared in this scope ` Please help thanks?

Comment: What compiler and what version of the compiler are you using?  What are the compiler options you're using?  The `std::unordered_map` exists for C++11 onwards.  If you're compiling using an old C++98 compiler or the settings are for C++98, you will not get `std::unordered_map`

Comment: Sorry for that i realized i spelt unordered incorreclty

Comment: Hey Paul How can i print it out i used `for (auto x : mapVehcile)
      cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;` but it only works with x.first and shows plateNo not the other info

Comment: Like for example when i look it up the vehcile shows the data of the vehcile which is found

Comment: `x->second` is the `Vehicle` itself.  Also, you should use references to the actual vehicle stored in the map, and not make copies of it.  `for (auto& x : mapVehicle) { Vehicle& v = x->second; .. }`